# How to fetch object from list inside list from Dio response

Tags: flutter

The Problem is here that I can't find a list of lists and fetch complete information of other lists from API in flutter using Dio.

```
  void fetchAllIndicatorsList(int ModuleId) async {
try {
  isLoading(true);
  var indicatorslist = await DioClient.fetchAllIndicators(ModuleId);
  if (indicatorslist != null) {
    Indicatorslist.clear();
first list ==>   IndicatorsChecklist.clear();

    Indicatorslist.value = indicatorslist;


    for(var i=0; Indicatorslist.length>0; i++){

      ==> second list IndicatorsChecklist.assignAll(Indicatorslist[i].indicators!.length.obs.toJson());

    }
  }
} finally {
  isLoading(false);
}
```

}[enter link description here](https://github.com/izaanhaleem/synergy_flutter)

Comment: Can you post a sample json that you are expecting, and the DioClient class that you have implemented.

Comment: Enter github link on my project please see it now

Comment: I have seen the link and it uses getx, I have not used in till no I need to check it i will update you.

Comment: please check y code and help me please

Answer (score 0):

Check out my example of getting lists in Dio

```
    Future getCourses() async {
    String endPoint = 'api/courses';
    final api = service.getApiClient();
    try {
      final result = await api!.get(endPoint);
      final rawList = result.data["data"] as List;
      final list = rawList.map((e) => Course.fromJson(e)).toList();
      return list;
    } on DioError catch (error) {
      return error.response!.data;
    }
  }
```

Comment: if (response.statusCode == 200) {

    Module1CheckList res = Module1CheckList.fromJson(response.data);
     //checklist = Stream.fromIterable(module1!).asyncMap((indicator) => indicator.indicators).toList();
    //moduleListController.IndicatorsChecklist.value= res.module1checklist?.map((indicator) => indicator.indicators).toList(growable : true);
    var indicatorlist= res.data?.toList().map((element) => element.indicators).toList();
    //res.module1checklist?.map((element) => element.indicators).toList(growable : true);

    return indicatorlist;
  }

Comment: i already use it

Comment: if (response.statusCode == 200) {
  
    Module1CheckList res = Module1CheckList.fromJson(response.data);
  
    var indicatorlist= res.data?.toList().map((element) => element.indicators).toList();


    return indicatorlist;
  }